# Need to create a visual hierarchy graphs in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I need to create an application read from the database & create a hierarchy graphs in my form, So I can access them from the form & change some properties or change the relation between the objects Like "Family Tree or Organization Structure" in C# & SQL Server...... if if any one know a 3rd party component to do that Please till me.

Comment: Why not use a TreeView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx

Comment: I need to view the data as an objects in my form  like
 http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/NSM_organizational_structure.png

Answer (score 1):

Holy cow! There are multiple ways to do this, but I'm not going to do your homework for you. Here's how I'd start:

1. You'll need to figure out the hierarchical relationships in the database.
2. Figure out how to pass that data to the view (html or whatever the platform).
3. Then you'll need to write CSS that reflects the hierarchy.

If you can give the data and more info I can help further.